# Configuring source directory in build.gradle for Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, gradle, plugins

I want to use Eclipse plugin to configure my test directories to run test cases. How should I configure these directories as test source directories in build.gradle file?

I couldn't find any answer on internet and gradle docs in this plugin are hopeless.

```
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
//for idea
idea {
module {
    sourceDirs += file('src')
    testSourceDirs += file('testDir1')
    testSourceDirs += file('testDir2')
}
```

}

Comment: It is unclear to me what exactly you want to do (what exactly are the _"test directories"_ here; should the tests be executed manually or in the Gradle build; etc.). Why you have `apply plugin: 'eclipse'`? For which Eclipse-specific tasks is this required?

Comment: I have a gradle file which needs to be configured for Idea and Eclipse IDE. There are directories which contains test classes in my project. In gradle you can specify them as source directories for Idea. I'm looking for that option for Eclipse. I have updated the code snippet.

Comment: The question is, why is this IDE-specific configuration required at all? What prevents you from configuring in `sourceSets { ... }` `main.java.srcDirs = ['src']` and `test.java.srcDirs = ['testDir1', 'testDir2']`?